# Coordinate after foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a pentagon. This works

```
\draw \foreach \alpha in {0,72,...,359} {
    \ifdim\alpha pt=0pt \else--\fi
    (270+\alpha:1) 
} -- cycle;
```

while this

```
\draw \foreach \alpha in {0,72,...,359} {
    (270+\alpha:1) --
} cycle;
```

gives the error `Cannot parse this coordinate.`

Can someone explain why?

Comment: See this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132162/3235

Comment: Very stupid interface from the part of LaTeX/TikZ! But thanks a lot for the explanation, this will save my computer a few occasions of being shouted at.

Comment: Why stupid? For example the proper way is `\draw (270:1) \foreach\x in{1,...,4}{--(270+\x*72:1)}--cycle;`.

Comment: Because I have to give special treatment to the first step. Not much of an issue in this simple example, but very nasty once it gets more complicated.

Comment: Open another question or edit this one to include the nasty case. Then you can ask for others' opinion for simplifications. People tend to love TikZ code golfing.

Comment: Do you know `regular polygon` shape? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212584/1952 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179847/1952

Answer (score 1):

You can define the path before to use it:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \xdef\p{}
  \foreach \alpha in {0,72,...,359}{
    \xdef\p{\p (270+\alpha:1) --}
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw \p cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]